# Entire forms gets re-rendered on every keystroke

Tags: reactjs, forms, performance

I have a complex form setup for user registration the problem is the entire form gets re-rendered on every
keystroke

### Application Structure

*I have given the architecture of my application below in top-bottom fashion*

**UserRegistration**
*The parent component which contains the single source of truth has the state in form of an object, it passes the input values as props to its child*

```
user:{
  number: '1234',
  firstName: 'Vaibhav',
  lastName: 'Shelke'
}
```

and its child is

```
<UserDetails
              getUserDetails={(userDetails, errors) => {
                this.setState({
                  userDetails,
                  errors: errors || {},
                  isSubmitable:
                    countLeaves(errors) === 0 && countLeaves(userDetails) > 0
                });
              }}
              values={this.state.userDetails}
              errors={this.state.errors}
            />
```

**UserDetails**
*The reusable component which contains basic values like firstName,lastName,number. this component gets the inputValues as well a function which reflects changes in the parent component, from its parent i.e UserRegistraion*

```
handleInput = (e, name) => {
    const { values, getUserDetails } = this.props;
    const userDetails = { ...values };
    if (e instanceof Date) {
      userDetails[name] = format('yyyy-MM-dd', e); // Date Input
    } else if (e) {
      userDetails[e.target.name] = e.target.value; // Text Input
    }
    getUserDetails(userDetails, validateUser(userDetails));
  };
```

**TextInput**
*The basic input component which actually changes it gets its value and handler from its parent ie. UserDetails as props*

```
const {
      label,
      name,
      onInputChange,
      icon,
      intent,
      helperText,
      labelInfo,
      value,
      type
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <FormGroup
        helperText={helperText}
        label={label}
        labelFor="text-input"
        labelInfo={labelInfo || ''}
      >
        <InputGroup
          type={type}
          intent={intent}
          leftIcon={icon}
          id={name}
          name={name}
          placeholder={label}
          onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
          value={value || ''}
        />
      </FormGroup>
    );
```

[image: issue-gif]

> All the above Components are class based Components

I have tried using the shouldComponentUpdate() but that still does not work

I have given the code in the summary of the problem[image]

Comment: It seems that on each change you do 'setState', which changes the state of the entire form. And that will trigger a re-render. Also, shouldComponentUpdate will always tell you the state is different, because isSubmittable and the empty error object will always be different (because you declare them inside the setState) .

Comment: A few things you can do to optimize this code:
1. pull getUserDetails in a separate function, don't declare it inside the prop
2. same with isSubmitable
3. same with the empty error object
4. add a debounce to the onchange of your textInput, to add some delay to the update
5. make all your inputs PureComponents